# SurfaceView How to setup android to only refresh the screen when it needs to be called?

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

So I have a thread dedicated to the my SurfaceView. However, during debugging I found that the the screen was being constantly redrawn. I feel this is waste. I'm looking for a way to check to see if indvalidate() or postInvalidate() was called so I only need to refresh the screen when it needs it.
Does anyone know what exactly I'm looking for or where I can start looking?

Answer (score 0):

You should be starting and stopping the dedicated rendering thread in `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceDestroyed()` when implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback` for your `SurfaceView`. This should be enough to limit drawing only when the `SurfaceView` is visible.

Comment: So I'm working on a kind of board game. And the board dosn't move or change around much in between turns. Right now, when the SurfaceView is visible the onDraw() method runs and runs and runs and runs while the thread runs. Which is what it's programmed to do. However I don't think that is very efficient. I only want the screen to update when there is a noticeable change. Right now a dedicated thread is not necessary, but later when I add animations it may come in handy.

Comment: I think the thread dedicated to your `SurfaceView` is the dedicated rendering thread I'm talking about. Regardless, you should be drawing according to my answer.